# on Double Click of NSCollectionViewItem open new window or view NSCollectionViewItem in same window

Tags: nscollectionviewitem

How to open a new window or view on double click of `NSCollectionViewItem`? My `collectionViewItem` is custom class derive from my `NSBox` so how to open can you please help me? 
And please send me some sample?

Answer (score 1):

My answer's a bit late in coming, but [this tutorial](http://www.springenwerk.com/2009/12/double-click-and-nscollectionview.html) sounds like it's pretty much what you need. It derives from Apple's [IconCollection example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/IconCollection/Introduction/Intro.html).